Showing that the Shannon entropy is a special case of the von Neumann entropy
I would like to show that the Shannon entropy ($\mathcal{S}(\rho)=-\sum_j p_j\ln p_j$) is a special case of the von Neumann entropy, $\mathcal{D}(\rho)=-\text{Tr}\rho \ln\rho$.
i.e.
$$-\text{Tr}\rho \ln\rho\Leftrightarrow -\sum_j p_j\ln p_j $$
Let $\rho$ be the probability density of an element, with two different outcomes, outcome $A$ and outcome $B$. This gives that we have the total probability of any outcome to be $\rho=1$ and the probability of each of the two outcomes to be respectively be $\rho_1=\frac12$ and $\rho_2=\frac12$. We form the matrix of outcomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac12 & 0 \\
    0 & \frac12
\end{pmatrix}  $$
This gives that we have the trace operator, $\text{Tr}\rho=1$, which gives the von Neumann entropy of $\mathcal{D}(\rho)=1\ln 1=0$ for the element with two outcomes.  This is a pure state, with lowest possible entropy.
However, when I calculate the Shannon entropy of the same case, I obtain
$$\mathcal{S}(\rho)=-(\frac12\ln\frac12+\frac12\ln\frac12)=\ln 2$$
Clearly, the results are different. So I need a different approach to show that these entropies are related. What is the best way to do that?
Thanks

I think you are misreading the definition of $\mathcal{D}$. $\rho$ is a matrix and Wikipedia suggests, that $\mathcal{D}(\rho) = - \operatorname{tr}(\rho \ln \rho)$ for the von Neumann entropy.

According to Wikipedia, the von Neumann entropy is defined as
$$\mathcal{D}(\rho) = - \operatorname{tr}(\rho \ln \rho),$$
where $\rho$ is a matrix. If $\rho$ is diagonal, $\ln(\rho)$ is also diagonal. In this case you find
$$\mathcal{D}(\rho) = - \operatorname{tr}(\rho \ln \rho)=-\rho_{11} \ln(\rho_{11})-\rho_{22} \ln(\rho_{22})$$
for
$$\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{11} & 0 \\
0 & \rho_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Otherwise you can find a unitary transformation $U$, such that
$$U\rho U^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix}
p_{1} & 0 \\
0 & p_{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
and you find
$$\mathcal{D}(\rho) = \mathcal{D}(U\rho U^\dagger)=-p_1\ln(p_1)-p_2\ln(p_2).$$

Thanks, that is a clear and precise answer.

For a proof of $\mathcal{D}(\rho)=\mathcal{D}(U\rho U^\dagger)$ see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444005/von-neumann-entropy-and-change-of-basis
